# Unable to locate an element implemented as <td> using Selenium Web Driver

Tags: c#, selenium

I wanted to locate the value of BNK1 using Selenium web driver by C#. my local website i found have 2 iframe. i have try to change to get my iframe to change to detail frame for me to get my value of BNK1 in the table. 
I had no idea what going on with the problem that i not able locate the iframe by using XPath.

but i having error "no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//iframe[@class='tabcontentiframe']"}

[image]
[image]

[image]

```
IWebElement detailFrame = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[@class='tabcontentiframe']"));
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(detailFrame);

IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table/tbody/tr/td[contains(text(),'BNK1')]"));
String text = element.Text;
```

Comment: Which page is it ?

Comment: @keepAlive, i want to get the element value as BNK1 by reading this web site.

Comment: Which website ? Which url ? If you want to get help efficiently, we (may) need to access the exact site you are talking about. Some peculiarities you are not aware of may be at stake.

Comment: its my local website, i wanted to get the value of the BNK1 in the table by using XPath

Comment: Well, so.... Is there an iframe in your page ?

Comment: yes, have iframe in my page

Comment: i still hit unable locate the iframe

Comment: Do you use [chrome devtools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools) to check your xpaths ? What does (in the console) `$x("//table/tbody/tr/td[contains(text(),'BNK1')]")` return ? Or actually before that, what does `$x("//iframe[@id='iframeHome']")` return ?

Comment: i follow your suggested solution, to apply xpath for iframe. but i having the error on the iframe. therefore i not able to check my result return in console. here is the error message : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//iframe[@id='iframeHome']"}

Comment: ***1)*** How many iframes do you have ? ***2)*** Can you get one element at least ?

Comment: i have 2 iframe, one using class and one using id.second iframe is the child of the first iframe. i have try to get the 1st iframe but not also having the same error.

Comment: Edit your question and report all what you have done/tryed. Also, copy/paste the source code of your local page. It is very uncomfortable to help you. Things that work for the entire planet do not for you. You have to help us help you. Also, if you want to improve your level in scraping, you will have to master Chrome Devtools (or analogous).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's get sure that your page is fully loaded before trying anything, using a heavy-hand approach,

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
```

Second, assuming the element you want to access is inside an iframe, you first need to switch to it. Actually, you mention in comment that you have two nested iframes,

```
// Let's switch to the parent frame
IWebElement tabcontentiframe = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[@class='tabcontentiframe']"));
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(tabcontentiframe);

// Let's switch to the child frame
IWebElement iframeHome = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[@id='iframeHome']"));
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(iframeHome);
```

Now, you can do

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table/tbody/tr/td[contains(text(),'BNK1')]"));
// or                                    By.XPath("//td[contains(text(),'BNK1')]")
// or                                    By.XPath("//td[text()='BNK1']")
```

---

When you are done, you may want to switch back to the main frame,

```
driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

Comment: @Jon do we agree that the parent iframe is the `tabcontentiframe` one ?

Comment: Thanks buddy, it working!!!!!  really thank a lot with the help and sorry about the unclear information to confuse. i will take note on next time

Answer (score 0):

You can find the element by using the relative xpath:

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//td[text()='BNK1']"));
```

Comment: i still having error invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //td[text(),'BNK1')] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//td[text(),'BNK1')]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: @JonathanK the xpath in the error is different from the one i have entered in the answer. Please pick the exact xpath from the answer and let me know if it works.

Comment: ya i had applied the exact answer provided from you. but i having error  no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//td[text()='BNK1']"}

Comment: @JonathanK the xpath in the error is containing a comma sign ‘,’ however in my ans, i have used an equal to sign ‘=‘

Comment: ya i had use the answer provided by you, i share you that is the error message appear at my console